# Why does YouTube use a table to layout it's search box?

Tags: html, html-table

I was wondering how is the virtual keyboard link is displayed on the youtube search bar, and an element inspection of the input element gave me this:

(I removed any classes and ids to make the code shorter since, the question is about the table)

Also, this code is of the top search input. Not the search result layout

```
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 30px; padding: 0px;">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <input name="search_query" value="" type="text" tabindex="1" title="Search" style="border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; outline: none;" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
           </td>
           <td>
              <div style="line-height: 30px;" dir="ltr">
                <a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <span>
                   <img src="//www.gstatic.com/inputtools/images/tia.png">
                  </span>
                 </a>
                </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

It struck me as really weird that they used a table for such a simple layout, but I guessed that "Hey, they must have a reason for doing so"
So can give me a good reason for the layout of the bar to be created that way? What purpose that could serve? Is there a reason that simple css positioning/layout wasn't chosen instead? Was the bar created by a newbie? WHY?

Comment: They use a table so that when you search, the dropdown options are just rows in the table. (Or at least, this does happen, but I'm not sure this is the real reason)

Comment: The search results are not displayed in that table. This table looks like it's only used for tha layout of the search input (at the top of the page), not for the search result section of the page

Comment: My youtube page does not have a single bit of table code there... See the code I get in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cGXsJe2i). Note: searched through the source code with both firefox and chrome, logged in and out.

Comment: I viewed the source by using the element inspector, so it is possible it is generated by JS

Comment: Notice it's the same for google search.

Comment: Contrary to common belief, the rumors of the deprecation of `tables` have been greatly exaggerated :)

Comment: the only reason I can think of is to take advantage of the vertical positioning properties

Comment: @DavidNguyen I just found myself in a case where two elements must be one next to another at all times, yet resizing the window caused the one to go bellow to another. Looks like if you put them in the same row of the table, that guarantees you proper flow of those elements :)